# Why "make default" run all dependency but "make" runs only one?

Tags: makefile

I have a simple Makefile

```
name=xxx

build:
    docker build -t $(name) .

run:
    docker run --rm -it $(name)

.PHONY: default
default: build run
```

When I do `make`, only `build` runs; but `make default` executes both `build` and `run` phrase.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default` isn't any special, a Makefiles *default* target is the one which was specified first.

```
name=xxx

.PHONY: default
default: build run

build:
    docker build -t $(name) .

run:
    docker run --rm -it $(name)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The "default" target, i.e.: the target to be built by default if no target was specified to `make` (as opposed to the target with the name `default`), is the first target found in the makefile.

Just place the following line:

```
default: build run
```

before any other target in the makefile. This will turn the target named `default` into the *default target*.

Answer (score 1):

The default target is the first rule in the makefile unless special steps are taken.  See:

- [Arguments to Specify the Goals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html)

You can change the default goal using `.DEFAULT`:

- [Special Built-in Target Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#index-_002eDEFAULT)